# SugarCrm REST .Net wrapper

Tags: c#, rest, sugarcrm

I am planning to write a simple SugarCrm .Net client.

Could anyone give me a pointer to a .Net wrapper/library for the SugarCrm REST api?

//lasse

Comment: check this [link](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/11/14/web-services-in-your-own-language-part-7-building-a-client-net-for-sugarcrm/)

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this done? And if so, could you help a brother out?

Answer (score 3):

Realize this is old, but in case anyone stumbles across this looking for a .NET wrapper for newer version of the web service (SugarCRM > 6.7), here is a wrapper I am currently building https://github.com/dlively1/SugarSharp

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrapper that uses SOAP called CandyWrapper, which is a bit old but could help you with a starting point on building your own.

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/08/10/web-services-in-your-own-language-part-6-candywrapper-for-net/

Comment: Yes,, I know that one. Although,, prefer not to write one of my own. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score -2):

I also realize this is old, but for SugarCRM CE 6.x I created SugarRestSharp. The sample I give below is in json, but the request would be in C# models. This implements **get_entry_list** SugarCrm Rest API method.

Passing request to RestSharp:

```
    dynamic data = new
    {
        session = sessionId,
        module_name = moduleName,
        query = queryString,
        order_by = string.Empty,
        offset = 0,
        select_fields = selectFields,
        link_name_to_fields_array = string.Empty,
        max_results = maxCountResult,
        deleted = 0,
        favorites = false
    };

    var client = new RestClient(url);

    var request = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.POST);
    string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    request.AddParameter("method", "get_entry_list");
    request.AddParameter("input_type", "json");
    request.AddParameter("response_type", "json");
    request.AddParameter("rest_data", jsonData);

    var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Request in json

```
    {
      "session": "olgg6hf5sqi6hk9u3tgpafbn66",
      "module_name": "Accounts",
      "query": "",
      "order_by": "",
      "offset": 0,
      "select_fields": [
        "name",
        "industry",
        "website",
        "shipping_address_city",
        "id"
      ],
      "link_name_to_fields_array": "",
      "max_results": 10,
      "deleted": 0,
      "favorites": false
    }
```

Response in json

```
    {
      "result_count": 10,
      "total_count": "58",
      "next_offset": 10,
      "entry_list": [
        {
          "id": "1e0eec64-8cc6-58ff-57f1-58533731b145",
          "module_name": "Accounts",
          "name_value_list": {
            "name": {
              "name": "name",
              "value": "New SugarRestSharp Acccount 1 10397"
            },
            "industry": {
              "name": "industry",
              "value": "Manufacturing"
            },
            "website": {
              "name": "website",
              "value": "www.sugarrestsharp1.com"
            },
            "shipping_address_city": {
              "name": "shipping_address_city",
              "value": "Los Angeles"
            },
            "id": {
              "name": "id",
              "value": "1e0eec64-8cc6-58ff-57f1-58533731b145"
            }
          }
        },
       ......... (other 9 items truncated)
      ],
      "relationship_list": [

      ]
    }
```

For more implementation and wiki check SugarRestSharp: https://github.com/mattkol/SugarRestSharp